# How to make a find in RoR with recursive-query like in CakePHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp, recursion, recursive-query

So, I have the next 4 models:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :folders
   belongs_to :payment
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :documents
   belongs_to :order
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :folder
end
```

How can make a find of one Payment and retrieve all the orders related to that Payment and all the folders of those orders and all the documents of those folders. In CakePHP setting the recursive in the params is enough but in RoR I don't know how to do it, do I have to use a gem? or it has other name?

Comment: have you tried `Payment.find(id).orders`

Comment: Yeah Cyzanfar I already try it but that only retrieve the orders and i want all, the Payment with the orders and folders and documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.includes()` with multiple nested models, something like:

`Payment.includes({orders: [{folders: :documents}]}).find(...)`

Comment: This is also a fast way to look up your association, we call this [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) which helps you avoid **N+1 queries**